# Acumular resultados de un COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de ventas de productos con los campos
**id_venta**, **fecha** y **producto**.
Esta consulta:

```
    SELECT DAYOFYEAR(fecha),COUNT(*) as con FROM ventas WHERE YEAR(fecha)=2016 GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(fecha)
```

Me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
DAYOFYEAR(fecha) con
1                 4
2                 5
3                 2
4                 1
5                 1
6                 4
```

La pregunta es ¿Cuál sería la consulta SQL para que el resultado quede de la siguiente manera?

```
DAYOFYEAR(fecha) con
1                 4
2                 9
3                 11
4                 12
5                 13
6                 17
```

Me refiero a **¿cómo acumular los resultados que van saliendo en el COUNT?**

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción sería calcular la suma con una subconsulta a la propia tabla ventas donde se cuenten todas las filas con fecha menor o igual a la actual. Algo como esto:

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(fecha), 
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM venta b WHERE YEAR(b.fecha)=2016 AND b.fecha <= a.fecha
       ) AS cuenta
FROM   venta a 
WHERE YEAR(fecha)=2016 
GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(fecha)
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchísimas gracias.